# How to remove errors in getmac program in C language?

Tags: c, file-io, include, system, file-handling

Please find below the code and the output which I am getting.

My C code is in `c:/turboc3/bin` directory
and my output `macid.txt` is in `c:/turboc3/disk`.

Here is the code which I am compiling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    //char mac[200];
    FILE *fp;
    clrscr();
    // fp=fopen("c:\macid.txt","w");
    system("GETMAC>c:/macid.txt");
    fp=fopen("c:/macid.txt","r");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        char line[128];
        while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fp)!=NULL)
        {
            char *nwln=strchr(line,'\n');
            char *ptr;
            if(nwln!=NULL)
                *nwln='\0';
            ptr=strstr(line,"Physical Address");
            if(ptr!=NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n",ptr);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Illegal command: GETMAC.
```

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Your program is calling something called `GETMAC.EXE`. Do you have an executable file of that name?

Comment: Use a command that is legal? Not really sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Code should be aligned so that people can see the structure.  Your code is (well, was, until @WhozCraig fixed it for you and us) anything but aligned, which conceals the structure.

Comment: The statement that `macid.txt` is in `C:/turboc3/disk` and the code that opens `C:/macid.txt` seem to be at odds with each other.  However, that is a secondary issue compared to the failure to find a program `GETMAC.EXE` to execute.  If you run GETMAC from the command line, does it produce output?

Comment: GETMAC.exe seems to be a 32 bit executable(with cmd.exe), and turbo C/C++ is 16 bit(executed in command.com)...Does anyone here think that could be an issue?

Comment: @Aniket, not sure but Turbo C++ 3 run also for 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

Illegal command: GETMAC implies, that it tries to run it but can't.

First, things to fix : Remember to escape \ inside string. Do not use / as path separator.

Then, Things to try, in approximate order: Try with full path to GETMAC. Try without redirection. Try with different program. Wrap GETMAC into bat file, which does the redirection.

Comment: why not use / as path separator?

Comment: Well, depends on OS, but with system() function under Windows, I'm almost certain it will not work. Windows/Dos path separator is \.

Comment: At the API level on Windows, `/` and ``\`` are interchangeable in file names.  If the interpreter used by `system()` is `CMD.EXE` though, it uses `/` to denote the start of an option and only allows ``\`` in file names.

Comment: Also, on Windows, \ always works, even in Java/mingw/cygwin, while / only works if it gets to win API unmangled. Also, I seem to remeber experiences that // does not work for disk share access, but this may again be just application program issue.

Comment: i dont know what the problem is ?? i tried it with every possible command . i tried it with forwared slash / as well as \ slash . i tried it with ipconfig/all command also but to no avail.every time i get the output as illegale command. the ipconfig/all command works fine in command prompt even getmac also give appropriate result in command prompt window

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your file macid.txt resides in `c:/turboc3/disk`, but - I think you can solve this problem by giving a full path to the `system()` function call.

LIke this:

`system("c:/windows/system32/getmac.exe > macid.txt");`

Comment: i dont know what the problem is ?? i tried it with every possible command . i tried it with forwared slash / as well as \ slash . i tried it with ipconfig/all command also but to no avail.every time i get the output as illegale command. the ipconfig/all command works fine in command prompt even getmac also give appropriate result in command prompt window ... friends please help. i am stuck. and when i give full path it shows illegal command cwindowssystem32getmac.exe(please note there is no forward slash or back slash in output)

Comment: @friend can I see a demo - a video of your code and the output in execution? I might be able to help you then

Comment: i dont know how to take the video of the screen. i will search it on net then will let you know . what i actually want to achieve is that i want to find mac address and write it in a text file and then read it from that text file and print it on screen on a windows platform. if you could help me with this coding i will be very grateful. there are several method listed online but due to my limited knowledge i was not able to apply those concept in my programming.